# How to get list of fonts used within one PDF file and copy them to another?

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I'm trying to convert a PDF1.7 document to a PDFA/3B one, and currently I need to get all fonts in the source document and copy them into the target (if this actually the way to do it). So currently I have the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i < source.GetNumberOfPdfObjects(); i++)
{
    var obj = source.GetPdfObject(i);
    if (!obj?.IsDictionary() ?? true)
        continue;

    var dict = obj as PdfDictionary;
    if (dict == null)
        continue;

    if (PdfName.Font.Equals(dict.GetAsName(PdfName.Type)))
    {
        var fontDescriptor = dict.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.FontDescriptor);
        if (fontDescriptor == null)
            continue;

        //What else?
    }
}
```

But I got stuck trying to get the font.

Is this the way to get the fonts from one doc or is there an easier way? And how does one copy them into the new doc?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the fonts in the document and copy them into the target document, you need the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPdfObjects(); i++) {
    PdfObject object = pdfDocument.getPdfObject(i);
    if (object.isDictionary() && PdfName.Font.equals(((PdfDictionary)object).getAsName(PdfName.Type))) {
        object.copyTo(targetDocument);
    }
}
```

However, please don't expect that all the content will be preserved on pages etc. This code just does what you ask for - copy the fonts to the new document. Preserving content and references to fonts is *much* more complicated than just copying the fonts.

Also, don't expect that by copying objects from an arbitrary PDF document to a document that you will make claim to be PDF/A-3B-compliant that document will acquire such compliance. This is simply not true. There are a lot of requirements PDF/A standard imposes and among them there are some requirements for fonts which are not necessarily fulfilled in your original document.

Comment: The original PDF (1.7) is created in Crystal Reports from my own app and I need to use iText to convert it to PDF A/3. The only embedded resources that I need are fonts (mainly TTF and occasional a barcode font) and images.